# Advice on scaling this code from querySelector to querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

I have a custom video player with JS, html and css. Crux of my issue here is I didn't anticipate scaling this from one video, to two videos and I'm looking to refactor this so I can play multiple videos on one page. I've tried rewriting everything into a `forEach` and haven't been able to crack it. Really just need someone to nudge me in the right direction here:

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fpqmz8hb/2/)

My thinking was to simply change `const player = document.querySelector('.custom-video-player');` to `const players = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-video-player');` and then scope something like:

```
players.forEach((player) => {
 // declare all the consts here... and event listeners
})
```

However, this approach isn't really working. Ideally I wanted to be lazy and not rewrite each instance of `player`. At this point I'm pretty stuck...

---

**HTML**

```
 <div class="cs__video">
  <div class="custom-video-player">
    <video class="player__video viewer" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"></video>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-video-player">
    <video class="player__video viewer" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"></video>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 /* custom video player javascripts */
  // declaring elements
  const player = document.querySelector('.custom-video-player');
  const video = player.querySelector('.viewer');

  /* Build out functions */
  function togglePlay() {
    console.log('playing');
    const method = video.paused ? 'play' : 'pause';
    video[method]();
  }

  /* event listeners */
  video.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
  video.addEventListener('play', updateButton);
  video.addEventListener('pause', updateButton);
  toggle.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
```

Comment: Cut down on the code, only add needed code!

Comment: I ended up declaring `var players = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-video-player');` followed by `Array.from(players).forEach(player => {});` but I want to leave the excellent contribution below as it's probably a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find it easier to manage the multiple players if you create each one from a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) that includes all the relevant setup and methods.

Once you create the class for all players it's easy to create as many as you like.

Here's an example that creates an array of two players from an array of video sources (also available as a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tvms0p8o/)).

```js
class Player {

  // We call `new Player()` with two arguments, the id
  // and the video source
  constructor(id, src) {

    // We assign both id and src to the class
    this.id = id;
    this.src = src;

    // Then we call two functions, one to generate the
    // video HTML, and one to add it to the page
    const html = this.generateHTML(id);
    this.addHTMLToDOM(html);
  }

  // We use a template literal to build our HTML
  // using the id and src we passed into the class earlier
  generateHTML() {
    return (
      `<div data-player=${this.id}>Player ${this.id}</div>
      <video controls width="250">
      <source src="${this.src}" type="video/mp4" />
      Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
      </video>`
    ); 
  }

  // This method simply adds the player HTML
  //  to the document body
  addHTMLToDOM(html) {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
  }
  
  // play and pause are a couple of example methods for
  // player control. `return this` allows for the methods
  // to be chained (see below)
  play() {
    console.log(`Playing video ${this.id}`);
    return this;
  }

  pause() {
    console.log(`Pausing video ${this.id}`);
    return this;
  }

}

// An array of video sources
const srcs = [
  'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4',
  'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4'
]

// `map` over the srcs array to create an array of new players
const players = srcs.map((src, i) => new Player(++i, src));

// An example to show how we can call the player instance methods
players[0].play().pause();
players[1].play().pause();
```

Comment: just what I needed, thank you for also including the class specs.